# Why are Azure Notification Hub tags not saving?

Tags: c#, android, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

I am trying to send a message to notification hub, but my tags are not saving.

I checked service hub with service hub explorer, and tags are empty:
[image]

Registration of device:

```
var hs = new HashSet<string>();
        hs.Add(tag);
        hs.Add(sys.ToString());
        switch (sys)
        {
            case SystemVendorEnum.Android:
                await Hub.CreateGcmNativeRegistrationAsync(pnsHandle, hs);
                break;
            case SystemVendorEnum.Ios:
                await Hub.CreateAppleNativeRegistrationAsync(pnsHandle, hs);
                break;
        }
```

Test method invocation that sends message to hub:

```
// param1: json payload, param2: tag
await Hub.SendGcmNativeNotificationAsync("{ \"data\": { \"methodId\":\"1\" }}", "ae65d2d5-103e-4023-a784-c5c8e2684db0");
```

Is there anything I am missing?
I don't have tags in notification hub:
[image]

Is that the case?

Answer (score 1):

I know, it's confusing, but there're two completely separate kinds of tags that have have no relationship to each other whatsoever:

1. Tags that are within the context of Azure Notification Hub service. Those apply to device registrations. So, it's Notification Hubs *service*-specific and describes devices. See [Routing and Tag Expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn530749.aspx) for more details.
2. Tags that as a concept of Azure Resource Manager (ARM). Those apply to any resource within Azure. So it's *platform*-specific and are used to describe *any* resource/service you have within Azure. See [Using tags to organize your Azure resources](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-using-tags/) for more details.

So when you call `hs.Add(tag)`, the associated tags apply to the device registration (i.e. 'tags of the first kind') and should show up in the Service Bus explorer:
[image]

And if you go to Azure portal and navigate to any resource (or as you did, to your hub), you'll see ARM tags there (i.e. 'tags of the second kind'):
[image]