# Azure: my notificationhub tags are not showing in the portal?

Tags: azure, push-notification, notifications, azure-notificationhub

I am using azure push notification with its rest api and i have registered a tag associated with a device but it does not show in my portal but when i call an api for Read All Registrations, so that tag is showing there even when i send a push notification for a particular tag the notification is also sending for that tag, i don't know why its happening.

I am using a free trial azure account, so is this happening because of that?

Comment: Before we go into details, could you confirm you're talking about NH tags and not about Azure Portal tags? Here's [an answer that shows the difference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38534891/182371).

Comment: azure portal tag by which we can send push notification according to group of devices @NikitaG.

Comment: Azure portal tags are used to tag Azure resources (such as storage accounts, VM, notification hubs etc) and have nothing to do with the tags specific to Notification Hubs. When you do a registration and associate NH tags with a registration -- those will not show up on the Azure Portal, because those are different tags. To see the NH registration tags, use either ServiceBus explorer or VS cloud explorer add-in.

Comment: ok thank you so much @Nikita G.